# How to delete everything outside of the print area in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and am trying to delete everything outside of the specified print area for every worksheet in my file. I have code that is working alright, but for some tabs, the print area begins in column B, and I need to delete column A because it is not in the print area. I cannot figure out how to rewrite my code to ensure that the column to the left of the specified print area will get deleted.

```
Dim FirstEmptyRow As Long
Dim FirstEmptyCol As Integer
Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        If .PrintArea = "" Then
            Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Else
            Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(.PrintArea)
        End If
    End With

    FirstEmptyCol = rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count).Column + 1
    FirstEmptyRow = rng.Rows.Count + rng.Cells(1).Row

    Range(Cells(1, FirstEmptyCol), Cells(1, 256)).EntireColumn.Delete
    Range(Cells(FirstEmptyRow, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: How are you declaring `FirstEmptyCol` and `FirstEmptyRow`? As `Long`? or `Range`?

Comment: Dim FirstEmptyRow As Long
Dim FirstEmptyCol As Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this additional code:

```
 If rng.Column > 1 Then
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, rng.Column - 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. Find the `PrintArea`and then using `Intersect` you could loop through the cells and find which cells are not in the `PrintArea`, `Union` the cells and then delete them at the end. Doing it this way you can delete everything that's not a part of the `PrintArea`, all at the same time. Hope this helps:

```
Sub testPrintArea()
    Dim printAreaRange As Range
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        If .PrintArea = "" Then
            Set printAreaRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Else
            Set printAreaRange = ActiveSheet.Range(.PrintArea)
        End If
    End With

    ' Get non print area cells and union them
    Dim nonPrintAreaCells As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Intersect(cell, printAreaRange) Is Nothing Then
            If nonPrintAreaCells Is Nothing Then
                Set nonPrintAreaCells = cell
            Else
                Set nonPrintAreaCells = Union(nonPrintAreaCells, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    ' do whatever...
    nonPrintAreaCells.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Column` and `Row` properties of a range to determine where it starts, like this

```
Sub DeleteOutsidePrintArea(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim rng As Range

    With ws
        If .PageSetup.PrintArea = vbNullString Then
            Set rng = .UsedRange
        Else
            Set rng = .Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        End If

        ' Delete columns to left, if any
        If rng.Column > 1 Then
            .Columns(1).Resize(, rng.Column - 1).Delete
        End If

        ' Delete rows above, if any
        If rng.Row > 1 Then
            .Rows(1).Resize(rng.Row - 1).Delete
        End If

        ' Delete columns to right, if any
        If rng.Columns.Count < (.UsedRange.Columns.Count + .UsedRange.Column - 1) Then
            .Columns(rng.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, .UsedRange.Columns.Count + .UsedRange.Column - 1 - rng.Columns.Count).Delete
        End If

        ' Delete rows below, if any
        If rng.Rows.Count < (.UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1) Then
            .Rows(rng.Rows.Count + 1).Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1 - rng.Rows.Count).Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Call it like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook '<~~~ Adjust to suit
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        DeleteOutsidePrintArea ws
    Next
End Sub
```